# How do i get input from win32 console application?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2013

I am writing a console application in c++, but the input isn't working. I thought the way to get input in c++ was cin.get() but apparently not, because it isn't working. Or maybe there is a different way in Win32, I have no idea.

I am so confused, can someone please help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: "doesn't work" is not a question. Show some code, what did you expect it to do, what did it do instead, and what you tried to fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can obtain the input by using `cin >> variable`

for example.

```
string str;
cin >> str;
```